# Editing heirarchical data in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Can anyone point me to some good resources that can help me understand the best way to work with hierarchical data in ASP.NET MVC 2?

I have an application under development that requires an interface allowing users to add, remove and modify children and grand-children of my root object.  The user can make multiple changes without persistance.  Only when they click "Save" will the entire object graph be saved.

I've seen one article that serialized the object and stored the data in a hidden field on the form but that seems really cludgy and I am dealing with a lot of data.

If I was doing this in standard ASP.NET, I'd be looking at using child windows and the like to display the edit pages and maintain an instance of the object being edited in Session - which is bad in and of itself.  But I've been told we are using MVC as we are standardizing our platforms (but not moving up to MVC 3 yet).

Essentially I need that app to display the properties of my root which includes a child collection of objects. The UI should allow the user to add new items to the collection, remove existing items and 'open' an item for editing.  These child items also contain their own list of grandchildren that is editable as well.  All of this needs to go on without round-trips across the wire to persist data (its a distributed architecture with all data access behind a WCF service interface).

The examples on www.asp.net all persist the data each time a single change is made, i.e. each postback.  But, that would require major schema changes and extra code to deal with temporary objects versus committed objects plus the overhead of the service calls each time.  I'm looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered looking at any client side libraries like Knockout.JS? I've found that it is excellent at manipulating collections and posting the final version as JSON. [Here](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html) is an example of what you can do with it. [Here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/) is an article about how to integrate it with MVC 2. This is my absolute favorite JS library.